# Setting options of a Kendo Grid that is inside an Editor Template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Inside the editor template of one of my Grids, `A`, I have another grid, `B`. I want to set `read` and `update` actions of this Grid based on the current Id in the `A`.

I've tried using Razor code inside the editor template like this:

```
// details grid: B
.Read("action", "controller", new { @Model.Id })
```

But `Id` was always null, probably because Razor is server-side.

So I've tried to set the Grid inside the main page, in the `Edit` event of the main Grid.

```
function EditHandler(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew())
        return;
    var detailGrid = e.container.find("#details").data('kendoGrid');
    detailGrid.dataSource.options.transport.read.url = "@Url.Action("", "")".concat('/', e.model.Id);
    detailGrid.dataSource.options.transport.update.url = "@Url.Action("", "")".concat("/", e.model.Name);
}
```

This doesn't work neither. The definition of the Grid in the editor template will overwrite these properties.

This is the main Grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<A>()
.Name("A")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(x => x.Id).Hidden();
    columns.Bound(x => x.Name).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: left" });
    ....
    columns.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Edit(); command.Destroy();
    });
})
.....
.Selectable()
.Navigatable()
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(x => x.Name);
    })
    .Read("", "")
    .Update("", "")
    .Destroy("", "")
    .Create("", "")
)
.Events(e => e.Edit("EditHandler").Save("SaveHandler"))
)
```

Inside the editor template of this class, `a.cshtml`, I have another Grid that I want its Edit and Read Actions include the `Id` of the Grid `A`.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<B>()
    .Name("B")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(.....
    })
    .....
    .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Selectable()
    .Navigatable()
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(x => x.Id);
        })
        .Read("", "")
        .Update("", "")
    ).ToClientTemplate()
)
```

**UPDATE**

```
function EditHandler(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew())
        return;
    var detailGrid = e.container.find("#details").data('kendoGrid');
    detailGrid.dataSource.read({ Id: e.model.Id });
    detailGrid.dataSource.update({ Name: e.model.Name });
}
```

As Dion noted, it needs 2 changes:

1. In the child Grid, `B`, set the auto bind to false: `.AutoBind(false)`
2. Set the `ID` with `read` method, not manually as I've been trying.

Comment: If you show how you've set up the grids (i.e. include code), then maybe someone can help you out. As it stands right now there's not enough information in the question to help you with how to proceed. Meanwhile you might want to take a look at this link and see if it helps: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy

Comment: I've updated my question. The link wasn't useful, I'm not using nested Grids, it's a popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome this case, I will trigger Grid-B's `read` manually inside Grid-A's `edit` event. Follow this setup:

Grid-B Config:

```
.AutoBind(false)
.DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
                    .Read("action", "controller")
                    .Update(url => url.Action("update", "controller").Data(paramData)))
```

Modify Grid-A `edit` function:

```
function EditHandler(e) {
    var gridB = $("#gridB").getKendoGrid(),
        model = e.model;

    gridB.dataSource.read({Id: model.Id});
}

// get Id for update 
function paramData() {
    return { Id : $("#Id").val(); };
}
```

Hope this help.

**Note**: Unlike read, update will be triggered after popup shown then `Id` field will be already have its value. Therefor you can use `Url.Action(...).Data()` for this case.

Comment: The `read` method works fine, but what should I use for update? It doesn't seem to have an `update` method.